# Headless Raspberry Pi 3 installation, attempting to use VNC, Putty, or boot with laptop with BIOS mode

Tags: networking, ssh, putty, vnc

I need a little help here. I own a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+.
My OS is Windows 10 on a Lenovo T430 laptop.
I have a problem: I need to boot my PI headless.
What I have is:

- a laptop
- Ethernet cable
- Android charger
- Micro USB car with an adapter

I should mention that I have been trying to connect at my college WiFi. In attempts to use *Putty*, I have come into several problems, the connection was refused by the computer ( I put the empty SSH file in my boot ) it only worked twice, but it seems to be deleted every time the Pi restarts over. Going to windows network configuration I checked the box that said to share all, for my lap top, checked the boxes for dynamic IP address to be obtained.

I am able to receive my IP address for the Raspberry Pi via its Ethernet port, but it only sends and does not receive. Using an IP scanner, the Raspberry Pi IP is always unreachable, but on the the network it has the IP of a different object. I believe that it has the same name as my computer, so I'm confused to why it always obtains that IP and not the one it is supposed to have according to ip scanner.

I was able to successfully use Putty twice, but that is it. I also listed my IP= on cmd file. I want to be able to most preferable boot into VNC or xming, but I'm willing to take whatever is easiest now.

If anyone can answer this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From searching around a bit, I came across [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63153/connect-pi-to-windows-10-with-internet-connection-sharing) which seems to be discussing a very similar issue.

From the answers shared there, it seems you'll need to manually configure the IP settings on the Rasp Pi to work with Window's Internet Connection Sharing.